# Block bootstrap as tablet size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a mighty problem. I have a project that are two websites, in which they share all the structure and css but one of them doesn't have the mobile version.
This is all done with bootstrap, but since bootstrap detects the window size (at least on my side), It will change to mobile version.

Without replicating css from my media queries and since min-width on body won't help, is there a way to block everything at col-sm ?

Thank you guys.

Comment: As far as I know if `col-x-sm` is declared as a class you would have to remove all instances in your HTML. Another work around would be to declare `.col-x-sm` on that particular document within a `<style>` tag, as this would overwrite any of the attributes.

Another option would be to write a simple JS script to find and remove all cases of `col-x-sm`

Comment: Imagining I would do the script, I would have to remove all col-xs and switch col-sm to col-xs right?

Comment: I remembered that wouldn't work...

Comment: Looking at it further you may be better off `removing` the desired classes first, `col-x-sm`. You may have to iterate over all possibilities as well, i.e. `col-1-sm`, `col-2-sm`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You *probably*, not certain, would have to either omit the `-sm` classes, or add in all the options to youre liking, i.e. `col-8-lg`, `col-8-md`, `col-4-sm`, `col-4-xs`

Using JS to **change** your current classes would be as simple as:

```
document.getElementsByClass("myElement").className = "newClass";
```

You could also **reset** all of your `col-x-xx` like so:

```
document.getElementsByClass("currentClass").className = "col-12-lg col-12-md col-12-sm col-12-xs";
```

The above would be tricky but doable, in the sense that this will replace all the classes for that element.

**Removing** all instances of a class:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
   ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/g , '' ) //This uses RegEx
```

You can also utilize JQuery:

```
$('#yourElement').addClass('yourClass');

$('#yourElement').removeClass('yourClass');

if ( $('#yourElement').hasClass('yourClass') DO SOMETHING)
```

Comment: It would be nice if it was that easy. I can't remove all col-xs, since there are sometimes thing like this - col-xs-12 col-lg-12.
But I could somehow do something reversal... that would detect one by one...

Comment: Absolutly, that's the biggest challenge I see as well.